# Call directive from controller with scrolltop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I can't seem to get elementById so I'm trying to figure out how to call a function within the directive.

```
<div class="class" home-page"></div>

module.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
        $scope.callDirect = function() {
            $scope.callFunction();
        };
}

module.directive("homePage", function ($window) {
        return {
            scope: { homePage: '&callbackFn' },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('scroll', function () {
                });

                scope.callFunction = function()
                {
                    console.log(element[0].scrollTop);
                }
            },
       };
});
```

I feel like this is really easy in javascript, but with Angular is really difficult. All I want to really do is scroll to top by clicking a button.

Comment: You are redefining the function `callFunction ` in directive!

Answer (score 2):

There are several frameworks, ngSmoothScroll and angular-smoothscroll are two, that will allow you to do what you are looking for with minimal effort on your part.

As to the Angular being harder statement. I can see where that comes from, at one time I thought the same thing. However, it really doesn't, if anything it makes it easier. It just requires a different way of thinking. So when the frustrations happen just keep the light at the end of the tunnel in mind.

I haven't ran this snippet to know if it will work or not but here is an example function to put in your directive

```
element.bind('click', function () {
    console.log(element[0].scrollTop());
});
```

What I'm not sure about is if the element[0].scrollTop is defined or not.